# Why can't I open a Sqlite database after setting a password using C# code?

Tags: c#, sqlite, encryption

I have a SQLite database. I use C# code to set its password. It all goes well with no error. However, I cannot open it using "DB Browser For Sqlite" client.

Here is my c# code:

```
SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(Config.ConnectionString);
cnn.Open();
cnn.ChangePassword(Config.DbPassword);
cnn.Close();
cnn.Dispose();
```

Here is the login picture:
[image]

Edit: 
If I use DB Browser for SQLite option "Set Encryption" then it works fine in both C# code and DB Browser for SQLite.

Comment: Post the login screen for the Db Browser or at least describe the steps.

Comment: @Igor, what do you mean by this? I thought it is the same. No?

Comment: No, they're not the same.

Comment: I turns out SQL uses "SQLCipher only recognises 256-bit AES" according to this link: https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/wiki/Encrypted-Databases and System.Data.SQLite; uses a different encryption.

Comment: @Shuaib - I misinterpreted your original question, I thought you were trying to change the user's password using the SQLiteConnection instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else facing this issue, I turns out SQL uses "SQLCipher only recognizes 256-bit AES" according to this link: github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/wiki/Encrypted-Databases and System.Data.SQLite; uses a different encryption. 
So if you just want to encrypt your SQLite DB then using System.Data.SQLite is does the job. But if you want to specifically encrypt it with SQLCipher then use SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_sqlcipher package.